# Update a text box in the aspx page with data from aspx.vb page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to pass data from aspx.vb page to the aspx page.

At the aspx.vb page i put a value(0 or 1) in the `textbox` that is `runat="server"`

and when the aspx page is loaded i check

example:

```
if($("#myTextBox").val() == "0"){
   .....
   ......
}
```

At the first time when the page is loaded things are correct(the text box is empty as supposed to be)

but from the 2nd time and on... the checking of the text box value isn't correct
(and i know that the value is correct and is in the text box)...the javascript doesn't recognize it.

hope it can help.....thanks

Comment: can you please clarify the last paragraph

Comment: i mean that after the text box value is updated from the function in the aspx.vb page and sent to aspx page the javascript code dosent happened => if($("#myTextBox").val() == "0"){
   .....
   ......
} thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if($("#<%=myTextBox.ClientID %>").val() == "0"){
   .....
   ......
}
```

You need to use #<%=myTextBox.ClientID %> for the JQuery get the correctly the DOM´s id